# Atypical loop output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

For the loop

```
int r = 10;
for(int h=0;h<r;h--)
{
    r--;
}
out.print(r);
```

the output is -2147483639. I'm not sure why the loop wouldn't be infinitely repeating, and I can't quite figure out the significance of the outputted number (besides the fact that it is near the int MIN_VALUE). What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r,h` starts out `10,0`, then each iteration counts down both by 1, e.g. `9,-1`, `8,-2`, and on.

Eventually, `h` reaches `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, i.e. `r=-2147483638, h=-2147483648`, before it underflows the `int` and becomes `r=-2147483639, h=2147483647`, at which point `h<r` becomes `false`, and the loop ends.

Result: `-2147483639`

*Note:* If you change `int` to `long`, the underflow will still happen, it'll just take a heck of a lot longer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to overflow, there is arithmetic underflow. In your case, the value of `h` underflows before `r` (at which point, it is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) and thus `h` is greater than `r` and the loop ends.

```
int r = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(r);
r--;
System.out.println(r);
```

Output is

```
-2147483648
2147483647
```

Comment: `h` underflows first, not `r`, making `h` positive with `r` negative, and `h<r` goes false and ends the loop.